# MaterialButtonToggleGroup in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button, android-jetpack-compose, modifier

I want to implement the [MaterialButtonToggleGroup](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button) in Jetpack Compose. This component looks like this (image taken from [here](https://www.journaldev.com/31950/android-materialbuttontogglegroup)):

[image]

So far, I got the following result:

[image]

Note, that the vertical grey border next to the vertical blue border are present. In the original, either the colored border or the grey color are present at a time. To make it more clear, have a look at this image with extra thick borders:

[image]

How can I achieve that the vertical borders between two buttons are not present? My current code looks like this:

```kotlin
    val cornerRadius = 8.dp

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            OutlinedButton(
                onClick = { indexChanged(index) },
                shape = when (index) {
                    // left outer button
                    0 -> RoundedCornerShape(topStart = cornerRadius, topEnd = 0.dp, bottomStart = cornerRadius, bottomEnd = 0.dp)
                    // right outer button
                    items.size - 1 -> RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 0.dp, topEnd = cornerRadius, bottomStart = 0.dp, bottomEnd = cornerRadius)
                    // middle button
                    else -> RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 0.dp, topEnd = 0.dp, bottomStart = 0.dp, bottomEnd = 0.dp)
                },
                border = BorderStroke(1.dp, if(selectedIndex == index) { MaterialTheme.colors.primary } else { Color.DarkGray.copy(alpha = 0.75f)}),
                colors = if(selectedIndex == index) {
                    // selected colors
                    ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = 0.1f), contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                } else {
                    // not selected colors
                    ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface, contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                },
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Some text",
                    color = if(selectedIndex == index) { MaterialTheme.colors.primary } else { Color.DarkGray.copy(alpha = 0.9f) },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                )
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example. Well done!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the [`MaterialButtonToggleGroup`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.3.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonToggleGroup.java#L528) to prevent a double-width stroke there is a negative marginStart on all except the first child drawing the adjacent strokes directly on top of each other.

Using the same solution:

```
OutlinedButton(
    modifier = when (index) {
        0 ->
            Modifier
                .offset(0.dp, 0.dp)
                .zIndex(if (selectedIndex == index) 1f else 0f)
        else ->
            Modifier
                .offset((-1 * index).dp, 0.dp)
                .zIndex(if (selectedIndex == index) 1f else 0f)
    },
    // Your code here
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Works absolutely fine, thank you very much! I didn't even know there is a `zIndex` modifier.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67036710/12528345) and the OP code, here's the full code (using material3):

(if you want to make the button group fill the width of the screen and for the buttons to share the width evenly, add `.weight(1F).fillMaxWidth()` to the `OutlinedButton` modifier. As is, the code will only take up as much width as necessary.)

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.zIndex

@Composable
fun MaterialButtonToggleGroup(
    items: List<String>,
    onClick: (index: Int) -> Unit = {}
) {
    val cornerRadius = 8.dp

    val (selectedIndex, onIndexSelected) = remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            OutlinedButton(
                modifier = when (index) {
                    0 ->
                        Modifier
                            .offset(0.dp, 0.dp)
                            .zIndex(if (selectedIndex == index) 1f else 0f)

                    else ->
                        Modifier
                            .offset((-1 * index).dp, 0.dp)
                            .zIndex(if (selectedIndex == index) 1f else 0f)
                },
                onClick = {
                    onIndexSelected(index)
                    onClick(index)
                },
                shape = when (index) {
                    // left outer button
                    0 -> RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = cornerRadius,
                        topEnd = 0.dp,
                        bottomStart = cornerRadius,
                        bottomEnd = 0.dp
                    )
                    // right outer button
                    items.size - 1 -> RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = 0.dp,
                        topEnd = cornerRadius,
                        bottomStart = 0.dp,
                        bottomEnd = cornerRadius
                    )
                    // middle button
                    else -> RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 0.dp, topEnd = 0.dp, bottomStart = 0.dp, bottomEnd = 0.dp)
                },
                border = BorderStroke(
                    1.dp, if (selectedIndex == index) {
                        MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                    } else {
                        Color.DarkGray.copy(alpha = 0.75f)
                    }
                ),
                colors = if (selectedIndex == index) {
                    // selected colors
                    ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(
                        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary.copy(alpha = 0.1f),
                        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                    )
                } else {
                    // not selected colors
                    ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(
                        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
                        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                    )
                },
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = item,
                    color = if (selectedIndex == index) {
                        MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                    } else {
                        Color.DarkGray.copy(alpha = 0.9f)
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
```